# Difference between 満足 and 円満

Tags: meaning, word-choice, sentence

I am confused about the usage of two words 満足 and 円満. According to dictionary 満足 is satisfaction and 円満 is perfection, peace, harmony and satisfaction.

So I used it in a sentence :

> 今の収入で円満じゃありません。

And my teacher corrected it as:

> 今の収入で満足できません。

Can anyone explain the situation when I should use 満足 and when to use 円満.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

満足 means “being satisfied (by/with something)”.
円満 means “being in good terms with each other”.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if it means being on good terms with each other then is it similar 仲良くする.

Comment: Yes, you are right